# How to create C# objects with parameters that may be not usefull / incomplete?

Tags: c#, constructor

Consider a c# class that has a constructor like this:

```
public class TestClass
{
    private UInt32 aValue;
    public TestClass(byte[] somedata)
    {
        // Here we do something with somedata
        // e.g. extract some values from some bytes
        aValue = somedata[1321]+ 256 * somedata[1321];
    }
```

as you can see in this example, my code relies on the fact that `somedata` is at least 1322 bytes long.

But what if it is not? I can only return from the constructor and thus leaving the object partly uninitialised, but nobody would notice that `aValue` did not become initialised. Throwing an exception requires the caller to catch this exception.

Sometimes i created a constructor method that had an `out` parameter and this parameter was set to indicate an error or not.

Sometimes i wrote some static methods in my classes that returned an object of the class type or null if the construction failed.

I know that this question may lead to many subjective answers - I think all of my earlier approaches have their own pros and cons.

But let me know what you think.

Greetings
Wolfgang

Comment: _"Throwing an exception requires the caller to catch this exception."_ What's wrong with this approach?

Comment: *"some static methods in my classes that returned an object of the class type or null if the construction failed"* - this (assuming constructor is `private` and class is `sealed`) would be the right approach to implement initialize pattern in c#

Comment: Good question ;-) I wouldn't mind throwing an exception. But my colleaques prefer to have a more straight forward approach to it. "If an object fails to do what it is expected to do, it should return an error". But within a constructor you cannot return an error (you can with the out parameter, but that requires the caller to implement the parameter even if he doesnt want to)

Comment: Constructor with `out`-parameter? Noooooooooooooo, don´t do this. Throw an exception. Caller has to check anyway, either for your out-param or for the exception, so better chose the latter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could perhaps do something like:

```
public static bool TryCreate(byte[] data, out TestClass obj);
```

and have it validate the inputs *before* trying to call the constructor.

The caller can then do:

```
if(TestClass.TryCreate(data, out var obj)) {
    // do something with obj
}
// optional: else do something... else
```

Comment: Or, simpler, return `null` for reference type and just check for it?

Comment: @Sinatr that is an option; I *like* using `null` for things like that - some people get very opinionated about *not* doing that; choose whatever works for you :)

Comment: This would be the same approach as in UInt32.TryParse(), and other methods like this... resembles a bit my static approach.

Comment: @WolfgangRoth the same pattern, yes

Comment: A method called Try... is commonly expected to return a bool and has an out argument. Returning null is valid with a different name for the method ;o)

Answer (score 1):

static method to create object seems good to me:

```
    public class TestClass
    {
        public static TestClass CreateIfValidData(byte[] somedata)
        {
            if (somedata == null || somedata.Length < 1322)
              return null;

            return new TestClass (somedata );
        }

        private Int32 aValue;
        public TestClass(byte[] somedata)
        {
            // Here we do something with somedata
            // e.g. extract some values from some bytes
            aValue = somedata[1321] + 256 * somedata[1321];
        }
    }
```

call like this:

```
byte[] somedata = new byte[10];
TestClass tc = TestClass.CreateIfValidData(somedata);

if (tc != null)  
{
    // only if the object was constructed, use it
}
else 
{
    // oops something went wrong...
}
```

Comment: You should rename the method to `CreateIfValidData` to make it more clear what will happen ... and creation will only take place if the data is valid

Comment: the public constructor may be / should be set to private in this case, so nobody can call it by accident.

Answer (score -1):

I voted for @Marc Gravell's answer, because TryCreate describes more precisely what the method does. And the object to be created is an out parameter, so it must be assigned to a variable.

Comment: This is not an answer. It wouldn't even be a useful comment.

Comment: :-/ but it describes why I took his answer. And thats usefull.

Comment: So make it a comment on his answer